# UIWebView - PDF HyperLink's crash

Tags: ios, pdf, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate, openurl

I have a **UIWebView** and I open a **PDF** in it. The PDF contains lot of hyper link's, I get a action sheet when I ***long press*** it.On pressing the open button in the action sheet and if the hyperlink is a valid URL it opens up in safari and if it is something else it crashes with **EXEC_BAD_ACCESS**, I do not get any crash logs here.

[image]

Need immediate help please.

Comment: Could you define "something else"?

Comment: I am not getting any log..what do you want me to define? The app crashes on clicking the 'Open' Button.

Comment: Please post your code of the "Open" action. We really *NEED* code to help you!

Comment: It is a default action sheet that comes up in UIWebView and I am not writing any code to bring it up.

Comment: Seems like you discovered a bug in iOS. I set up a small test project, trying to open a link from a PDF document loaded inside a UIWebView and as soon as I tap on the "Open" button in the action sheet the app crashes (on iPhone 5 with iOS 6.1.3 and on the simulator too). "Add to Reading List" and "Copy" work fine. I suggest you should file a bug report at https://bugreport.apple.com and send them a sample project that demonstrates the issue. Just for reference, I used this PDF http://edoc.hu-berlin.de/nordeuropaforum/2011-500/all/PDF/2011-500.pdf

Comment: @BjörnKaiser Thanks for the effort, is there some way to block the action sheet that comes up?.

Comment: I don't know of a way to do that, sorry. I've tried setting the `dataDetectorTypes` to `UIDataDetectorTypeNone` but this seems not to work with PDF documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this helps :

> https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2483470?start=0&tstart=0

Seems to be a common error.